# Handle custom tab bar for iPhoneX

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, iphone-x

I am creating a custom tabbar. And I am struggling to properly place it in the viewcontroller so that it fits well in both iPhoneX and iPhones with a home button.

When I use `SafeAreaLayoutGuide` to anchor it at the bottom I get the following results:

**iPhone X:**

[image: iphonex]

**iPhone With Home Button:**

[image: iphone_home_button]

And when I use `bottomAnchor` of the view:

[image: iphonex_clipped]

In the code, I have a custom bar view that I am adding as a subview and adding constraints to pin it at the bottom:

```
    let tabView = WoofTabBarView(barItems: barItems)
    tabView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    tabView.delegate = self
    tabView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(tabView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        tabView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
        tabView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
        tabView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabContainerView.bottomAnchor),
        tabView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
        tabView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0)
    ])
```

I can fix it using some hack like adding view to cover the bottom, or check for the device version etc. but I want me `tabbarview` class to be intelligent enough to handle it on its own instead of relying on the `tabbarviewcontroller` to fix it.

For better understanding of the code, you can check the repo on Github:
[WoofTabBarController](https://github.com/ihak/WoofTabBarController)

Comment: I have a very similar situation (although maybe not as slick a tab bar), and what i did was use `SafeAreaLayoutGuide` and then insert the view between the tab bar and `bottomAnchor` of the same background colour. so buttons are always accessible on all iPads  but for the ones without home button there is just more of the grey background

Comment: @zaitsman I did the same to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

> Replace tabView's class to with `WoofTabBarView`

```
let parentView = UIView()
parentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
parentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
let tabView = UIView()
parentView.addSubview(tabView)
tabView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
tabView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.addSubview(parentView)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    parentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
    parentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
    parentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor), // Add parentView's Bottom Constraint to View's Bottom
    tabView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.topAnchor),
    tabView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60.0),
    tabView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.leadingAnchor),
    tabView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.trailingAnchor),
    tabView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor) // Add tabView bottom constraint to Safe Area
])
```

[image: iPhone X]
[image: iPhone SE]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am looking for a way to handle this inside the WoofTabBarView. Not outside of it.

Comment: @HAK Red colored view will be your `WoofTabBarView` and Green will be the Parent View of `WoofTabBarView`. Didn't this work for you? You will get same behavior as native TabBar.

Comment: Not it won't work. If a user changes the background of the tabbarview, then both goes out of sync. Also what happens when I add functionality to provide an image as a background of the tabbarview.